# Resize Highchart chart with core-splitter in polymer 0.5

Tags: html, css, highcharts, resize, polymer

I have a Highcharts based scatter chart and a table in two different divs. I need to be able to resize the height of the chart with it's contents adjusting as per the resized area. I am using a core-splitter between both of these divs as shown below

```
    <div id="top_container" vertical layout center-justified>
    <div id="chartArea"></div>
     <core-splitter direction="up"></core-splitter>
    <div id="tableArea">
    <aha-table>table related code here...</aha-table>
   </div>
```

I basically need to achieve something as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/149/

the css for chartArea is like this

```
#chartArea {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The problem is that Highcharts lib don't watch for changes in the HTML container. Only watcher is for `browser.resize` event. Does `core-splitter` provide any handler/callback when resizing happen? If it does, then use `chart.setSize(width, height)` when user changes height of the `chartArea`.

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus , I did exactly what you said and it worked !